# create a resizable edittext that goes from some maximum text size to minimum text size in every line separately

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to create an edittext in which text size starts from some maximum size say 80sp. When entered text reached to end of the edittext width text size should decrease so that entered text can fit in single line this should continue until text size becomes some minimum say 18sp. When text size is 18sp and if more text is entered then new text can go into the second line but in the second line. In the second line, the size should be 80sp only. Means in the first-line 18sp and in second-line 80sp.

I am facing a problem that is when the text reaches to end of the first line and more text is entered sometimes it creates the second line without reducing the size in the first line.

This is a video link for a better understanding of my issue. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eRgr6YaSqNc06anaDZg2kETTKCgi-hC7

My code

```
  mainBinding.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            update(s.toString());
        }
    });

private void update(String s){
    float size = getNewSize(s);
    mainBinding.editText.setTextSize(size);
}

private float getNewSize(String line){
    float currentSize = 80;
    while (hasLineBreak(line, currentSize)) {
        currentSize -= 1;
    }
    return currentSize;
}

private boolean hasLineBreak(String text,float size){
    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    textPaint.setTextSize(size);
    Layout layout =
            new StaticLayout(
                    text,
                    textPaint,
                    350,
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    1,
                    0,
                    true);

    return layout.getLineCount()>1;

}
```

I want to implement the same as Instagram type mode story feature.

Comment: i think you should give a try to SpannableStringBuilder that will be much more simple to manage different text sizes.

Comment: [refer](https://instagram-engineering.com/building-type-mode-for-stories-on-ios-and-android-8804e927feba) to this docs from INSTAGRAM